# How to record the event that an attachment from Outlook has been clicked to run or downloaded to the disk?

Tags: windows, email

I am developing a solution to monitor security events on Windows.

Two of the events to monitor are:

- an attachment from an email (Outlook) has been clicked to run or downloaded to the disk
- a link from an email has been clicked

Does anyone have experience in how to achieving these two things?

Comment: I would say asking this question on stackoverflow would be better. You are more likely to get programming related help over there.

Comment: Agree with @Limit.  This is not an infosec question, its a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways I can think of to do this.

- Outlook Extension

  The easiest is to write a script. The [MailItem.BeforeAttachmentRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff870101.aspx) lets you see what the user is going to open/save, and even allows you to cancel it if you find it suspect. You can also use several other related event hooks to customize the experience (check the docs). No hardcore kernel-level programming is required.
- Kernel Hook

  You could also implement a generic file hook that runs in the background and reports activity from the Outlook executable, but this is probably more cumbersome than it needs to be. The Windows API allows you to monitor when files are created, but you wouldn't be able to see specifically when an attachment is previewed (as far as I could determine from the docs).

Either way, you can then deploy your package through a Group Policy Object so that it can be invisibly installed without the user's knowledge. Once installed, you can choose to log those attachments through the usual channels, such as an Event Log that can be viewed in the Event Viewer.

Comment: Now to make it a better answer: OP asks specifically about two events. Are they both equal? I.e. "this" in your "do this" applies to both? If so, I think the answer should start with a sentence explaining that no separate methods for the two are required.